# If $dQ=\Lambda\, dP$ then $E^Q\left[ X \mid \mathcal{G}\right]=E\left[ X \Lambda\mid \mathcal{G}\right]/E\left[ \Lambda \mid\mathcal{G}\right] $

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The statement:

> Take two probability measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, such that $\mathbb{Q}\ll\mathbb{P}$ with
>   $$d\mathbb{Q}=\Lambda d \mathbb{P}.$$
>   Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{F}$. Then for any $\mathcal{F}$-random variable $X$ we have
>   $$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[ X | \mathcal{G}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[  X \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right]}{\mathbb{E} \left[ \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right] }.$$

Part of the proof I understand:

> Assume $X \geq 0$. We note that by the definition of conditional expectation, for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$:
>   $$\int_G \mathbb{E} \left[ X  \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right]d \mathbb{P} =\int_G X \Lambda d\mathbb{P} =\int_G X d\mathbb{Q} =\int_G \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] d \mathbb{Q}=\int_G  \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \Lambda d \mathbb{P}.$$
>   Now we use the definition of conditional expectation to take another conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal{G}$. Since $G \in \mathcal{G}$:
>   $$\int_G  \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \Lambda d \mathbb{P}=  \int_G \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right] d \mathbb{P}.$$
>   But $ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right]$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and so
>   $$\int_G \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right] d \mathbb{P}=\int_G \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[  \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right] d \mathbb{P}.$$
>   Thus, since in particular $\Omega \in \mathcal{G}$, we get
>   $$\int_{\Omega} \mathbb{E} \left[ X \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right]d \mathbb{P} = \int_{\Omega} \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[  \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right] d \mathbb{P}.$$

??? Part of the proof:

> Since $X \geq 0$ (and $\Lambda > 0$) this means that $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and hence $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s. we have
>   $$\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[ X | \mathcal{G}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[  X \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right]}{\mathbb{E} \left[ \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right] }.$$

Could somebody give me a hint about what happened in that last part of the proof. How can we just omit those expectations? I was thinking it's maybe because the random variable $\mathbb{E} \left[ X \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right] - \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[  \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right]$ is non-negative, then we could omit expectations if I'm correct, but I don't know how to prove that it is.

Thanks for any help on this. I appreciate it.

Comment: At the end of the day, one has two random variables $U=\mathbb{E} \left[ X \Lambda | \mathcal{G}\right]$ and $V=\mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[X | \mathcal{G} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[  \Lambda | \mathcal{G} \right]$, both $\mathcal G$-measurable, such that $E(U;G)=E(V;G)$ for every $G$ in $\mathcal G$. This ensures that $U=V$, $P$-almost surely.

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe give me a hint on how to prove the result you're using. That is: if $X,Y$ are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variables on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and if $\int_A X d\mathbb{P}=\int_A Y d \mathbb{P}$, $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $X=Y$ $\mathbb{P}$ a.s.

Comment: Try the events $A=[X>Y+t]$ and $A=[X<Y-t]$ for various positive $t$.

Comment: Thanks. Does the following make sense?

Comment: First of all, since $X-Y$ is a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable, $A=[X-Y \geq t] \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B=[X-Y \leq -t]\in \mathcal{F}$, where $t>0$. Then, by the assumption we have $\int_AX d\mathbb{P}=\int_A Y d \mathbb{P} \geq \int_A (Y+t) d \mathbb{P}$, so it follows that $t\mathbb{P}(A) \leq 0$. Similarly, we have $\int_B X d\mathbb{P}=\int_B Y d \mathbb{P} \leq \int_A (Y-t) d \mathbb{P}$, so it follows that $t\mathbb{P}(B) \leq 0$. So since $t>0$, we conclude that: $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(B)=0$, meaning $X=Y$ $\mathbb{P}$ a.s.

Comment: Right, $P(A)=P(B)=0$, but why does this entail that $X=Y$ almost surely?

Comment: Probably there's a simpler way than this, but I wouldn't know it, not even completely sure if this is right...If $A_n=[X-Y\geq \frac{1}{n}]$, then $A_1 \subset A_2 ...$, so we have $\mathbb{P}(\cup_n A_n)=\lim_n \mathbb{P}(A_n) \Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X-Y>0)=0$. Similarly, by defining $B_n=[X-Y\leq -\frac{1}{n}]$ we get $\mathbb{P}(X-Y<0)=0$. So finally, since $\mathbb{P}(X-Y>0)+\mathbb{P}(X-Y<0)+\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=1$, we conclude that $X=Y$ $\mathbb{P}$ a.s.

Comment: Precisely. Well done. Maybe post all this as an answer?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your help...I'll definitely post this as an answer.